# How to get FBFriendPickerViewController to show ALL friends

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

1)

There has been a change in the FBFriendPickerViewController with the recent version of the Facebook SDK. It used to give you a Friend Picker with all of your Facebook friends but now it only shows friends that have used your app. Handy, but I have functionality in my application that needs to choose from the users entire friends.

Senario = I am trying to use the friend picker to choose a friend and then after selection a segue is performed that shows a view controller that gives the user details of that friend they just selected. That means the selected friends "id" must persist to the next view controller so I can retrieve friends information using the "id" on the next VC (which makes FBFriendPickerViewController handy because of the friendPicker.selection property).

Question = Does anyone know a way I can get a list of the users entire Facebook friends in the friend picker?

2)

Alternative = Another possible solution could be this way by creating a table view and loading the table up with the JSON from Facebook. From there I can load the friend data into the cellForRowAtIndexPath and that all works fine.

```
NSString *accessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;

NSString *surl = @"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@&fields=picture,name,id";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:surl, accessToken]];

NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *d, NSError *e) {
    if (e==nil) {
        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:d options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];


friends = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jsonData[@"data"]];

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:                  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

idx = indexPath.row;


NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[friends sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

f = friends[idx];

// Configure the cell...

//cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_lightgrey.png"]];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_blue.png"]];
cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
//cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fbDefaultPic.png"];
cell.textLabel.text = f[@"name"];
UIImage *theImage = f[@"image"];


if (theImage==nil) {

    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;


NSString *url = f[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = img;
        //NSMutableDictionary *newFriend = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:f];
        //friends [idx] = newFriend;
        //newFriend [@"image"] = img;



    });

});

}

else {

    cell.imageView.image = theImage;
}


return cell;
}
```

Problem with alternative = I am finding it extremely difficult to persist the "id" of the selected friend using this way. (Would be super helpful if tableView had a .selection property like FBFriendPickerViewController, but it doesn't...).

Question (for alternative) = Can anyone help me with a way that I can create a tableView of Facebook friends and am able to extract the "id" so I can store it in a singleton variable and use it in my other view controller?

-To summarize -

Problem with 1) = Not all friends show up, but can get friend's "id".

Problem with 2) = All friends show up, but can not get friend's "id".

Comment: Any solution? If this is the case from now on, I will probably just dump the Facebook SDK. This was the main use case for me.

Comment: Nah haven't found anything yet. You just have to query for friends yourself.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? Is there a link in the documentation?

Comment: Looks like as of July 1 2014 (SDK v3.15.1), the alternative/2) doesn't show all friends, unless I'm doing something different (I ran your code, up to getting the jsondata). And I do receive the id. I wonder if this is due to an API update?

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook Platform Changelog**

The most recent version of the API is Version 2.2, which was introduced on October 30, 2014.

Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: 
The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1